# Test if integer series is strictly increasing

Tags: bash

I would like to test if a list of integer values (e.g stored in a file, one per line) is strictly increasing, using a bash script.

Is there any simple/concise way to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if the file's contents remain the same after sorting numerically and filtering duplicated lines:

```
cmp file <(sort -n file | uniq)
```

At least GNU `sort` can do this check directly:

```
sort -c -u -n file
```

(The [POSIX `sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) documentation mentions this too so it should be supported everywhere.)

Comment: But that won't work for **strict** increasing, will it?

Comment: @fiddler if you omit the "filtering duplicated lines" part you'll get your solution for a _strictly increasing_ sequence

Comment: The `sort` solution seems perfect.

Comment: Note that GNU sort (as opposed to Solaris sort for instance) seems to read the input fully before reporting the disorder even if the disorder is on the second line.

Comment: Actually, not fully, just some amount of data: 40k in my tests, though is affected by the -S option (though I couldn't manage to make it read _less_).

Comment: Yes, even when [checking](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/sort.c;h=85fc38f73d2bc8c0ce6a8be14c1153dc4013532d;hb=HEAD#l2783), it starts by [filling a buffer](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/sort.c;h=85fc38f73d2bc8c0ce6a8be14c1153dc4013532d;hb=HEAD#l1746).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean, check that each line is a decimal integer that is one plus the decimal integer in the previous line, then:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {n = $0; next}
     $0 != n+1 {status = 1; exit}
     {n = $0}
     END {exit status}'
```

Replace the `$0 != n+1` with `$0 <= n` to check for strict increasing by any value, not only one. In that case though, you'll probably prefer the [`sort -c` approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212064) unless you want it to stop reading at the first disorder, or you want to support number formats (hexadecimal, floating point notation...) not supported by `sort` (like when your sort doesn't support `-g`)

Comment: _strictly increasing_ simply means that for an integer sequence, the current value is greater than the previous. It makes no assumption that it's increasing by one, or even by any regular amount. Just that each number is the sequence is bigger than the previous.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'length(p)&&++p!=$0{print "Not OK";exit};{p=$0}' file
```

for increasing one per line. To check current is bigger than previous:

```
awk 'length(p)&&++p<=$0{print "Not OK";exit};{p=$0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The extremely concise version would be something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'NR > 1 && $1 < prev { printf( "error at line %d\n", NR); exit; } { prev = $1 } '  $1
```

This non concise code would be

```
#!/bin/bash
l=1     #line number count
p=0     #previous line value
for f in `cat $1`
do
    if [ \( "$f" -lt "$p" \) -a \( "$l" -ne "1" \) ]   #chk for all lines, except first
        then    echo "$f is less than $p on Line $l"
        break
    else
        p=$f  #set previous
    fi
    l=$(expr $l + 1)   #increment line number
done
```